# Count distinct values based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, distinct, countif

My Excel workbook features a table containing approximately 50K record. I am currently using a formula to count distinct values based on two criteria, namely: ID & Region

Doing this via a formula makes my workbook incredibly slow. I was therefore wondering if you had any idea how I could convert it into an efficient VBA loop instead.

```
.Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(IFERROR(1=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)),0),1,0)"
```

[image]

Desired results in column C. The VBA code must be able to highlight unique values by labeling column C with "1". When faced with a duplicate entry, the code must only label the last entry of the range as as unique "1" (see ID 3).

Comment: Are the results sorted as you show?  For VBA, I'd suggest reading the data into a VBA array; then using a Dictionary object to check for duplicates.

Comment: It occurs to me that creating this column may not be your desired end result. For example, if you are planning to use it as a filter, so as to return only the last unique value, there are more efficient methods of accomplishing that, in either VBA or Power Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unique 'Descending'

- It is assumed that the table (one row of headers) starts in cell `A1` and that the header is already written in the first cell of the destination (resulting) column (`dCol`).
- Adjust the worksheet name (`wsName`) and the destination column (`dCol`).
- The `Delimiter` has to be a string that is not contained within the data.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetUnique()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dCol As String = "C"
    Const Delimiter As String = "|"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 2).Offset(1)
    End With
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim cString As String
    
    For r = rCount To 1 Step -1
        cString = sData(r, 1) & Delimiter & sData(r, 2)
        If dict.Exists(cString) Then
            dData(r, 1) = 0
        Else
            dict.Add cString, Empty
            dData(r, 1) = 1
        End If
    Next r
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.Resize(, 1).EntireRow.Columns(dCol)
    drg.Value = dData

    With drg
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - rCount - 1).Offset(rCount).ClearContents
    End With
    
End Sub
```